# How much memory a null value occupy?

Tags: php

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php

While studying it, my understanding for how variables are declared is changed completely. I came to PHP from .net background. What my understanding was when we decalre an

`int x = 32;`

Since we declared int, so it take `4 bytes` space in memory, and null values don't occupy any space rather they points to null reference in memory.

While studying this PHP manual, i was unable to conclude a single thing, that how null values take up space in memory.

Thanks

Comment: The issue is that PHP variables are 'dynamic', as regards the type, and value of information they hold. So, when assigned it could be a number. The next line it could be assigned a string! So, when you declare a variable it can hold every type possible! i.e. it is a record. What type and value it currently holds can be found by looking at the fields of the record. The answer provided explains more. i.e. you declare variable `$x` that can hold anything. Then it is set to type int and value of 32. But those are just fields in the record `$x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should occupy only the part for var declaration (an not for the content) a variable is essentially a zval_struc

```
typedef struct _zval_struct {
   zvalue_value value;        /* variable value */
   zend_uint refcount__gc;    /* reference counter */
   zend_uchar type;           /* value type */
  zend_uchar is_ref__gc;     /* reference flag */
} zval;
```

take a look a this for some tips  http://www.slideshare.net/jpauli/understanding-php-memory/12-PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php